# Hibernate: getting one field from a child table

Tags: hibernate

Let's say I have tables

```
Person(personId, name) 
Address(addressId, fk_Person_personId, address, creationTime)
```

So one person might input more than one address.

Is it possible to create a `Person.getMostRecentAddress()` method, based on `Address.creationTime`?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `max()` within your HQL query.

```
select max(p.address.creationTime) from Person p where ...
```

I did not try it out, but within the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-aggregation)

> "HQL queries can even return the results of aggregate functions on properties:", but there they use only one indirection and not two like `p.address.creationTime`.

Another approach would be:

```
select max(a.creationTime) from Address a where a.person.id = ...
```

that should do the trick I guess.

Comment: I don't want the creationTime value, but the Address object with the most recent creationTime for this Person